# App crashes on startup

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sigabrt, sigkill

Im trying to make an iOS App with Xcode, until now everything worked well.
I have an Navigation Controller on MainWindow.xib, first it loaded RootViewController NIB, but now I changed it to main because I want a launching screen before. But now the app crashes on startup with error "SIGABRT".
Thread 1 0 abort:

```
0x99771bdd  <+0167>  jmp    0x99771c0c <abort+214>
```

in 11 UIApplicationMain it is:

```
0x0036da9b  <+1175>  xor    %eax,%eax
```

and in main.m:

```
  int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

where it stopped.

The new files:
StartScreen.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface StartScreen : UIViewController {
    RootViewController *rootViewController;

    IBOutlet UIButton *showList;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *rootViewController;

@end
```

StartScreen.m:

```
#import "StartScreen.h"

@implementation StartScreen
@synthesize rootViewController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    [showList addTarget:self action:@selector(showListButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return self;
}

-(void)showListButtonClicked {
    if(self.rootViewController == nil) {
        RootViewController *view2 = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"rootviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
        self.rootViewController = view2;
        [view2 release];
    }
    rootViewController.title = @"Test";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.rootViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

The app directly shuts down after 1 second when the startup image appears....

(Another problem is, that before this error came the error "SIGKILL" appeared after closing and restarting the app in simulator)

Please help :)

Comment: Can you confirm if the app enters proper methods when debugging? Does your App Delegate code execute properly?

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RootViewController 0x8c822b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key showList.'`

Do you think that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your connections in .XIB file. It looks like the StartScreen is using a file, where "File Owner" is set to RootViewController.

Comment: In StartScreen.xib it says Class is "StartScreen". But when I delete the UIButton or its connection to UIButton *showList in Interface Builder in the view it works...

Comment: Another possibility is similar error in RootViewController's .xib file. Check it in the same manner.

Comment: that also belongs to RootViewController class...

Now I tried to add a button manually, but its not visible :D
When theres no button it just works fine...

Comment: BTW: What's the exact name of RootViewController's .xib file?

Comment: RootViewController.xib but its in Xcode under a different menu entry. Is it then in a different directory?

Comment: In the line `[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"rootviewcontroller" bundle:nil];` you try to init with rootviewcontroller.xib file, which doesn't exist. Change this line to `[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];`

Comment: Yeah, thank you!!! Works:) *another problem is fixed too*

Now only problem SIGAKILL is still there when I close and restart application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6261/discussion-between-lordtwaroog-and-drp96)